# How to list all databases name installed?

Tags: android

In my aplpication, i'm using several databases. 
I'm looking for display all the databases installed for my application and their corresponfing version.

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#databaseList()

As for the version, you may need to open them first.